# Update state gradually over several seconds

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I am trying to simulate a script running on a web app. The idea is that a script is running in the background and is launching http requests, these requests should then be shown as `<p>` in a div. But I don't want it to go too fast. Firstly, updating the state too fast doesn't update it correctly, and secondly it makes it difficult for the user to see.

I have tried using a setTimeout, but this does not work, as it seems to be setting a timeout and then continuing to setState without waiting.

```
AddParagraph = () => {

for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++){
 setTimeout(function(){
 this.setState({
    urls: [...this.state.urls, www.url.com/i]
 })},2000)
 }
}
```

I have read that setting state in a for loop is not a good idea because it will not have time to render/update that fast. But I don't see a good idea to do this, should I not use state for this?

Comment: An option would be to multiple the timeout with index `})},2000*i)` This will schedule setState every 2 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to add requested URLs and log it on the webpage.

So it seems like you are confused about updating state, "imperatively" using a `for` loop.
React is more of a declarative in nature and your component typically react to "state" changes.

So instead of using `setTimeout`, which requires using a `for` loop, let's "react" to the state changes at a set internval.

### Class Component (CC) version

As I see `this.state`, I assume you are using a CC.

```
class ClassRequestViewer extends Component {
  state = {
    urls: [],
    postId: 1
  };

  // To be used to clear the interval
  //  to prevent memory leaks
  intervalId = undefined;

  // Add a paragraph while setting the new post ID
  //  together in one shot.
  addParagraph = () => {
    const newUrl = `${urlRoot}/${this.state.postId}`;
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      urls: prevState.urls.concat(newUrl),
      postId: prevState.postId + 1
    }));
  };

  //  You would want to initialize the interval only ONCE
  // as the changing the state in `addParagraph` will
  // cause `ClassRequestViewer` to re-render (in `render()` below).
  componentDidMount() {
    this.intervalId = setInterval(this.addParagraph, timeout);
  }

  // ⚠ is important!
  // We need to make sure to clean up to prevent memory leak.
  // OR else, the interval will run even if the component is unmounted
  //  and unavailable.
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.intervalId && clearInterval(this.intervalId);
  }

  //  Whenever "addParagraph" updates the state,
  // This gets called, so will show the requests sent automatically.
  render() {
    const { urls } = this.state;

    return (
      <ul style={{ listStyle: "none" }}>
        {urls.map(url => (
          <li key={url}>Request sent to {url}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

Now you can see the list of requests sent to render at the given interval.

[image: working demo]

You can follow along on CodeSandbox
[image: Edit so.answer.57364530]

---

### Function Component (FC) version

I've also implemented the same CC version in FC below using hooks (`useState`, `useEffect`).

The code looks smaller as `useEffect` effectively "co-locate" concerns (`setInterval` & `clearInterval`) in one place.

```
function RequestViewer() {
  const [urls, setUrls] = useState([]);
  const [postId, setPostId] = useState(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    function addParagraph() {
      const newUrl = `${urlRoot}/${postId}`;
      setUrls(_ => _.concat(newUrl));
      setPostId(postId + 1);
    }

    const intervalId = setInterval(addParagraph, timeout);
    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, [postId]);

  return (
    <ul style={{ listStyle: "none" }}>
      {urls.map(url => (
        <li key={url}>Request sent to {url}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

There is no `for` loop there either, because `useEffect` is updated whenever `postId` is changed, which is every `timeout` seconds in `setInterval`.

---

> I want it to be started on an onClick event and stopped after X amount of rows. This seems to run endlessly?

As you mentioned in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57364530/update-state-gradually-over-several-seconds/57365348?noredirect=1#comment101217596_57365348), it runs continuously.
To be able to "start/top" the process, you'd leave the "viewer" as the viewer and handle the display on the parent.

So when you "start" the process, the viewer `ClassRequestViewer` will start the request and show you the result, and clicking on "stop" will unmount the component (this is why I used `componentWillUnmount` to `clearInterval`).

I've updated the `App` to have `start/stop` buttons.

```
function App() {
  const [isStarted, setIsStarted] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Request Viewer</h1>

      {!isStarted && (
        <button onClick={() => setIsStarted(true)}>Start the request</button>
      )}
      {isStarted && (
        <>
          <button onClick={() => setIsStarted(false)}>Stop Requests</button>
          <ClassRequestViewer />
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

When you click on `Start the request` button, it sets `isStarted` to `true`, thus `ClassRequestViewer` is loaded, and you can see the request.

*The code below is loaded*

```
{isStarted && (
  <>
    <button onClick={() => setIsStarted(false)}>Stop Requests</button>
    <ClassRequestViewer />
  </>
)}
```

When you click on `Stop Request` button, which sets `isStarted` to `false`, thus, the `ClassRequestViewer` unmounts, (which in turn calls `componentWillUnmount -> clearInterval` to clean up).

And then you get to see `Start the request` button again.

```
{!isStarted && (
  <button onClick={() => setIsStarted(true)}>Start the request</button>
)}
```

Below is the working demo of the updated `App`.

[image: start stop buttons]

Comment: Thank you for this, it is exactly what I want. Altough I am a bit confused on how to "stop" the behaviour and how to "start" it as well. I want it to be started on an onClick event and stopped after X amount of rows. This seems to run endlessly?

Comment: @Moddah I've updated the reply to answer your comment.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Very elegant solution

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the `for` loop runs immediately to completion while all the async operations (here the `setTimeout`) are started.

This is because the `for` loop does not wait for an asynchronous operation to complete before continuing on to the next iteration of the loop and because the setTimout callbacks are called some time in the future. Thus, the loop completes its iterations and then all the callbacks for setTimeout fire simultaneously updating the state at once causing race conditions. Also, keep in mind that `setState` is itself async.

You can use promises and async/await to make your code synchronous and behave the way you're expecting like this -

```
const delay = (time, i) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Setting state", i);
      this.setState({
        urls: [...this.state.urls, `www.url.com/${i}`]
      });
      resolve();
    }, time);
  });
};

const addParagraph = async () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    await delay(1000, i);
  }
};

addParagraph();
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: This seems to work exactly as I want it, thank you. Altough, what is the advantage/disadvantage of doing it this was as oppose to doing it the way @Sung M. Kim by using lifecycle methods?

Comment: @Moddah My answer is geared towards how you were approaching it and the issue you were facing with your code. Talking about advantage/disadvantage for this...I don't think it makes sense since both are doing the same thing with state, in just different ways! ...one using hooks as functional component and mine using class component...lifecycle methods being used in both, explicitly or implicitly